# How to create circular progress loader on filling form inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a circular progress loader that shows each progress of filling form input . As form is filled completely . The loader should show 100%. Here's the whole code I am using .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" required="required"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" required="required">
Age: <input type="text" name="age" required="required">
Gender: <input type="text" name="gender" required="required">
City: <input type="text" name="city" required="required">
Locality: <input type="text" name="locality">
Address: <input type="text" name="address">
</form>
<p id='percentage'>0% completed</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="myctrl" ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<p ng-model="counter"></p>
<input type="text" value="{{counter}}" class="dial">
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>

$(".dial").knob({
readOnly: true,
fgColor: "#00ABC6",
bgColor: "#666666",
thickness: 0.2
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').on('change', function(){
var cntreq = 0;
var cntvals = 0;
$('input').each(function(i, val) {
if($(this).attr('required') == 'required') {
cntreq++;
if($(this).val() != '') {
cntvals++;
}
}
});
var count = (cntvals/cntreq)*100;
//$('#percentage').empty();
//$('#percentage').append(count+'% completed');
angular.element($("#myctrl")).scope().anyFunc(count);
//$('.dial').val(count);
});
});

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.anyFunc = function (var1) {
alert(var1);
$scope.counter = var1;
};
});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

This loader changes as wechange value of input tag so I am using angular js to pass count variable to input value . So as we fill each input it will change automatically .

I found this loader from here "http://jsfiddle.net/CU7KM/"

and form percent calculator from here "http://jsfiddle.net/ktozh5sd/2/".
I am trying to achieve a circular loader that show progress of every input field.

Comment: Why are you mixing so much Angular and jQuery?  For what you're doing, you shouldn't need any jQuery

Comment: Why are you posting such a snobby comment? For what you're doing, you shouldn't need any comment.

Comment: I am just trying to check whether i am getting any value or not... if i get value in counter variable this would have to work .I searched alot but dint get any answer for making a circular progress on filling form inputs . Please check those links individually you'll get what am i trying to achieve

Comment: Well, @SomeRandomName, it was a constructive comment, unlike yours.

Comment: Please guys try to find the solution .. If possible